# Unable to initialise OpenALPR

Tags: c#, visual-studio, openalpr

I am trying to integrate OpenALPR with C#. After removing some errors now when I try to execute the program, the program starts, but when the image is selected for results it gives an error message:

> error initializing openalpr

Please suggest a way forward.

Comment: Have you checked your settings:  `config_file` - path to the `openalpr.conf` file and `runtime_data` path?

Comment: Yes! i had errors before and while clearing them i have copy pasted above mentioned folders to the right locations manually. are there any other settings in visual studio as well which i have to check? @KateOrlova